# What's the meaning of "revolving deeds"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

My friend made a sentence:

> Don't humiliate a person lest you should get revolving deeds.

Probably, he wanted to say that we should not humiliate a person, because that person may humiliate you in return someday.

Is that sentence correct? Is this what "revolving deeds" means? 
When I look it up in dictionaries, I find no other meanings than:

deed→a good/bad act; a kind of document
revolving→something that is able to be turned around a point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a (slightly inaccurate / inappropriate) allusion to [*Revolving door (politics)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revolving_door_(politics)) - whereby people move between working for government legislative / regulatory authorities and the commercial organisations they're supposed to oversee.

The specific point being made by OP's friend is probably better encapsulated by [Wilson Mizner's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson_Mizner)...

> *Be nice to people on the way up because you'll meet the same people on the way down*

...or [this more recent "pithy saying"](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-true-that-what-goes-around-comes-around) (apparently from the 1970s, precise origin unknown)...

> *What goes around comes around*

But I don't think the average Anglophone would recognize any specific meaning to the collocation *revolving deeds* unless they were "spoon-fed" the intended meaning by context.

Answer (score 3):

By **revolving deeds** your friend is referring to things **going around and coming back** (***revolving***) and things that people do and say (***deeds***).  You are known by your **deeds**, and the result of your deeds it can be interpreted as [**karma**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/karma), a notion that many cultures have

> If you put bad things out into the world, bad things will come back to you
>
> A tree is known by its fruit; a man by his deeds. *(Saint Basil)*
>
> **You shall reap what you sow**
>   *You will harvest what you plant*
>   *Your actions will come back to you*

Your friend may have meant that the person you humiliate will humiliate you back in retaliation or revenge

> Treat others as you would want them to treat you

or the greater world may do something to you.

Your friend is saying:

> **if you are unkind to someone, don't be surprised if something bad happens to you**

Comment: I already know what he was trying to say. My question is: Is it correct to use "revolving deeds" in that sense? Did he use good English?

Comment: Yes, it seems fine, most people would understand given the context.

Comment: Your friends use of **lest** kind of makes it sound like a proverb in a nice sort of way, much better than **because**, maybe could drop the **should** which would be understood anyways

Comment: I don't think most folks would understand "revolving deeds" without someone explaining it. It sounds like a shady real estate practice to me, not karma. Deeds don't revolve. They come back to haunt you. They return to you threefold. They do not spin in place. @Gurpreet